# Beginner python and montecarlo

Tags: python, montecarlo

I have been having trouble following all the montecarlo tutorials as they are seem to start to advanced for me to follow. I have a few months of python experience.  So far I have been unable to find any on the basics.  Any tips or links to the basics of montecarlo and python would be great.

Im looking to make a simple montecarlo simulation.  One simulation would involve selecting a random outcome for event 1 from the distribution and then allocating a score.  Then another random outcome for event 2 and so on.   So 1 run of the sim would give me 3 scores.  Thanks in advance for any help with this

I will be trying to rum a sim 10000 times approx on a bigger dataset.  Should I be trying to do this in numpy?

Probability distribution

```
         outcome 1  outcome 2  outcome 3  outcome 4  outcome 5
event 1        0.1        0.2        0.5        0.6          1
event 2        0.1        0.3        0.4        0.7          1
event 3        0.1        0.5        0.6        0.7          1
```

Scores

```
         outcome 1  outcome 2  outcome 3  outcome 4  outcome 5
score 1        100        400        200        600        100
score 2        200        600        300        700        500
score 3        400        100        500        300        200
```

Comment: Hi! Maybe look into https://pandas.pydata.org/? DataFrames are really good for bigger datasets and are also fast... It is based on numy

Comment: I don't understand what you're really trying to achieve. Do you want to run a Monte Carlo Tree Search algorithm ? Or only to select one value randomly inside an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
import numpy as np


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_events = 3
    n_scores = 3
    n_outcomes = 5

    events = np.random.random((n_events, n_outcomes))
    scores = np.random.random((n_scores, n_outcomes))

    print("events", events.shape, events, "\n")
    print("scores", scores.shape, scores, "\n")

    run_scores = np.zeros(n_events)
    for run_idx in range(n_events):
        selected_idx = np.random.choice(n_outcomes, 1)
        run_scores[run_idx] = scores[run_idx][selected_idx]

    print("run_scores", run_scores.shape, run_scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

The random module in python is particularly useful when dealing with random simulation problems. You can use the [random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function to simulate the above experiment.

The `choices()` function lets you specify the outcomes and the corresponding weights, along with the number of simulations to run. The function returns a list of the results. We can use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) object to tabulate the results and get it in dictionary form.

```
from random import choices
from collections import Counter

"""
         outcome 1  outcome 2  outcome 3  outcome 4  outcome 5
event 1        0.1        0.2        0.5        0.6          1
"""
# outcomes and weights for event 1 as per the probability distribution you provided
outcomes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cumulative_weights = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1]
num_simulations = 10000

scores_list = choices(population=outcomes, cum_weights=cumulative_weights, k=num_simulations)

# Use a Counter to tabulate our results. This will give us a dict-like object
scores = Counter(scores_list)

for outcome in outcomes:
    print("Outcome {}, Score: {}".format(outcome, scores[outcome]))

# Output ->>
# Outcome 1, Score: 1022
# Outcome 2, Score: 1009
# Outcome 3, Score: 2983
# Outcome 4, Score: 1045
# Outcome 5, Score: 3941
```

The code sample above demonstrates how to run 10,000 simulations of one event. Use multiple sets of outcomes/weights as per your requirement.